# Масштабирование графика

Tags: c#

Нужно построить график, в котором `x,y` - дробные числа с миллионной частью (к примеру `10,176485`). Нужно, чтобы график строился при изменении не целой, а дробной части хотя бы на одну сотую.

Comment: с построением графика проблем нет, вопрос в чем, я считываю с устройства значения x, y и  динамически строю, но штука в чем, значения получаемые с устройства меняются на тысячную, в лучшем случае на сотую, при таком изменении точки не строятся

Answer (score 1):

- Рассчитайте и сохраните в некоторую коллекцию `IEnumerable<Point>` сетку точек с заданной точностью. *Т.е, скажем значения `(x, y)`: `(0.01, 25), (0.02, 25.3), ...`*
- Вывод на экран выполняется примерно следующим образом:

---

```
foreach point in points
    pixel = TransformPointIntoPixelCoordinates(point);
    FillPixelWithColor(pixel, color);
```

- Смысл вышенаписанного понятен - для каждого значения точки в исходных "функциональных" координатах *есть однозначное отображение этих самых координат в **текущую отображаемую область на экране,** которое вам и предстоит провести.*

---

- [**Касательно**](http://lurkmore.ru/images/5/53/11318-131945-5c812c9bc8c08b83a416dccd875eac53.jpg) второй части вопроса.